# why it is a good practice to name the argument in the function prototype?

Tags: c

I was told that it's considered good practice to name the arguments  in the prototypes.

so let's say we have two files `main.c` and `test.c`

**main.c**

```
// and I didn't use header file here, it is just for demo purpose
//

extern void funcTest(int);

int main()
{
   funcTest(2020);
   return 0;
}
```

**test.c**

```
void funcTest(int num);
{
    ...
}
```

since it is a good practice to name the argument in the function prototype we can declare the `funcTest` in `main.c` as

`extern void funcTest(int num);`

but theoretically, we can put any name we want as and the names don't need to match the one in definition in `test.c`:

```
extern void funcTest(int n);
  or
extern void funcTest(int abc);
  or
...
```

due to the flexibility of the naming, then isn't a good practice **not** to name the argument in the function prototype?

Comment: the goal is to self document your api, consider api with `(int weight, int size)` hard to know what args are for `(int, int)`

Comment: Example: `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`

Comment: If the function takes several arguments, you know which argument belongs to the Nth parameter by looking at well descriptive identifiers for the parameters at the prototype.

Comment: @amjad Parameter names are not required when the function name gives the idea what arguments are expected. For example void sort( size_t, int[*] );

Comment: Not required, but helpful and readable. Sometimes I am familiar with what a function does, say `int func(int, int)` but forget which way round the arguments are. It saves time looking up the implementation. If different names are used you'll again waste time looking to and fro to ensure you are using the right function.

Comment: All the above is true, and some documentation-generation tools will mine headers for function prototypes. Having documentation with unnamed parameters isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to name your variables in such a way that reading it clarifies the argument.

consider these two prototypes:

```
void StoreString(char * homeAddress);
```

and

```
void StoreString(char *s);
```

Ideally it doesn't make much sense but in larger projects it tells you that StoreString specifically manipulates some string that is a homeAddress. In larger projects this is very helpful. For example in embedded systems you might see a prototype like:

```
int ManipulateData(int **sensorData, int dataBytes, bool *sensorStatus);
```

which I hope doesn't need much explanation. You can get an idea what function is taking and what it might be doing.

Now to answer your question "Why it's a good practice" is because in large projects we've these prototypes in header files.

So if you are looking into the header files you won't understand what a function is doing  if it's name is not clear. Even if the name is clear and the description of arguments is not clear then you've to open the definition of function in some other file where it's defined. In larger projects files might be located in different directories and all of this tracking takes time.

Proper naming saves you a lot of time in larger projects. It's well said that **TIME IS MONEY** after all.